# "arithmetic exception, numeric overflow, or string truncation string right truncation" em pesquisa utilizando LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, firebird

Tenho uma tabela em um banco de dados Firebird

```
CREATE TABLE CIDADE (
CID_CD              SMALLINT NOT NULL,
CID_DS              CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CID_UF              CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
CID_DISTANCIA_SEDE  SMALLINT NOT NULL,
CID_CD_ALTERNATIVO  INTEGER NOT NULL,
CID_DT_LK           DATE NOT NULL);
```

Estou fazendo uma consulta utilizando LINQ nas colunas dessa tabela e estou recebendo o erro nas colunas do tipo CHAR:

> arithmetic exception, numeric overflow, or string truncation
>   string right truncation

Identificando o problema, percebi que o tamanho dos campos do tipo String estão estourando o limite dos campos. O que não estou entendendo é que estou passando exatamente quantidade limite do campos.

Segue o meu código:

```
  public IQueryable<Cidade> Pesquisar(Cidade cidade)
    {
        string uf = cidade.UF; // "SP" por exemplo
        var query = pctxContexto.Cidade.Where(c=> c.UF.Contains(uf));
        return query;
    }
}
```

Mapeamento:

```
//Mapeamento de tabela
        ToTable("CIDADE");

        //Chave primária
        HasKey(t => new { t.Codigo });

        //Propriedades
        Property(t => t.Codigo).HasColumnName("CID_CD");

        Property(t => t.Descricao)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(20)
            .HasColumnType("Varchar")
            .HasColumnName("CID_DS");

        Property(t => t.UF)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(2)
            .HasColumnType("Char")
            .HasColumnName("CID_UF");

        Property(t => t.DistanciaSede)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("Smallint")
            .HasColumnName("CID_DISTANCIA_SEDE");

        Property(t => t.Codigo_Alternativo)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("Int")
            .HasColumnName("CID_CD_ALTERNATIVO");

 public Cidade()
    {
        Codigo = null;
        Descricao = string.Empty;
        UF = string.Empty;
        DistanciaSede = 0;
        Codigo_Alternativo = 0;
    }

    [Key]
    public int? Codigo { get; set; }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public string UF { get; set; }

    public Int16 DistanciaSede { get; set; }

    public Int32 Codigo_Alternativo { get; set; }
```

Alguém poderia me explicar o porque desse erro e qual a maneira mais elegante de resolver?

Comment: Poste sua classe `Cidade`, por favor.

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta adicionando a classe cidade

Comment: Poste também sua classe `Codigo`, por favor.

Comment: Sua classe `Cidade` tem um campo `Key` que é `nullable`? Isso não pode estar certo.

Comment: O código não é classe é um campo inteiro e pode ser nulo, caso seja nulo uma trigger adiciona o código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira mais elegante de resolver é por decoração de atributos. Dispensa até a *Fluent API* que você está usando:

```
public class Cidade
{
    public Cidade()
    {
        Codigo = null;
        Descricao = string.Empty;
        UF = string.Empty;
        DistanciaSede = 0;
        Codigo_Alternativo = 0;
    }

    [Key]
    public int? Codigo { get; set; }
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    [StringLength(2)]
    public string UF { get; set; }

    public Int16 DistanciaSede { get; set; }

    public Int32 Codigo_Alternativo { get; set; }
}
```

Se você usa `@Html.EditorFor()` nas *Views*, os campos HTML já são gerados com limitação de caracteres. [`[StringLength]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) suporta também colocar uma mensagem de erro personalizada por atributo.

---

**EDIT**

Não sei se pode ser pelo fato de você estar usando `like`, mas eu não usaria `contains` para pesquisa por sigla de estado:

```
var query = pctxContexto.Cidade.Where(c=> c.UF == uf);
```

Comment: Por curiosidade, o fato de na tabela o campo `CID_CD` ser inteiro e chave e na classe ser um objeto do tipo `Cidade` não é para dar algo errado?

Comment: Essa chave primária tá esquisita mesmo. Nem precisa aquela *Fluent API* que ele colocou. Só não entendi o problema com `Cidade`. A meu ver, a classe está correta, pelo menos na declaração.

Comment: Erro meu de interpretação.

Comment: O erro acontece mesmo quando eu atribuo 2 caracteres(Que é o limite do campo). Ele Adiciona "%SP%" por exemplo e gera o erro. Segue a consulta gerada:
`SELECT 
*
FROM  "CIDADE" AS "C"
WHERE "C"."CID_UF" LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE CAST(_UTF8'\' AS VARCHAR(8191))

Parameters:
Name:p__linq__0 Type:VarChar Used Value:%MG%`

Comment: @PauloHenrique Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: obrigado pela atenção de todos, de fato, realizei alguns testes aqui e realmente o erro ocorre pelo fato de está usando contains. Eu até posso alterar o código para `c=> c.UF.Equals(uf)` para sigla que é mais viável porém, o erro acontece em descrição também que nesse caso o like seria ideal.

Comment: @PauloHenrique A resposta atende à sua pergunta? [Veja aqui os próximos passos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Obrigado!